# Elastic search-9200-connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying all the ways to connect to elastic search. wrote powershell and shell scripting according to my project. not able to connect to port number 9200.
Tried to change to other port number.
But result is still same.

Comment: Can you paste the output when you try to connect to elasticsearch?

Comment: Might also make sense to include your script, in case there's something wrong with it.